# Converting DeclaredAccessibility to C# string in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, microsoft.codeanalysis

I want to implement interfaces in my code generator, so I need to convert `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Accessibility` (i.e. from `ISymbol.DeclaredAccessibility`) to their represented modifier keywords.

This enum is used in code analysis APIs for describing access modifiers of a class or its members.

For instance, if you have `public void MyMember()` its `ISymbol.DeclaredAccessibility` will be `Accessibility.Public`.
I need to create such a method declaration, thus I need a way to convert `Accessibility.Public` to `public` and so on (take note that just `ToLower` will work only for simple cases, it won't generate `protected internal`).

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the [SyntaxFacts.GetText(Accessibility)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxfacts.gettext) Method:

```cs
string publicKeyword = SyntaxFacts.GetText(Accessibility.Public);
string accessibilityKeyword = SyntaxFacts.GetText(accessibility);
```

*Namespace*: [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp)
*Assembly*: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll
*Package*: [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp)
*Available since:* v3.0.0

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(Accessibility.NotApplicable, "")]
[InlineData(Accessibility.Private, "private")]
[InlineData(Accessibility.ProtectedAndInternal, "private protected")]
[InlineData(Accessibility.Protected, "protected")]
[InlineData(Accessibility.Internal, "internal")]
[InlineData(Accessibility.ProtectedOrInternal, "protected internal")]
[InlineData(Accessibility.Public, "public")]
public void Accessibility_To_ModifierKeyword(Accessibility accessibility, string expected)
{
    string actual = SyntaxFacts.GetText(accessibility);

    actual.Should().Be(expected);
}
```